# How to display query results in python code in html?

Tags: python, html, python-development-mode

I'm trying to display the results of a python query in html.
I have the following error and I can't find the solution.
I leave code.
Thank you for your support

I expected it to show the name of a product, its price and the supermarket
but i got this error

JsException(PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 429, in eval_code .run(globals, locals) File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 300, in run coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals) File "", line 1, in ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4' )

```
code

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>python</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
    <py-env>
        - plotly-express
      </py-env>
    </head>
<body>
    <py-script>
            from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
            import requests
            import time
            import webbrowser
            import webbrowser

            print("Accediendo a la web..")
            print('.')
            time.sleep(2)

            url = 'https://www.jumbo.cl/salchichas-llanquihue-250-g-5-unida-2/p'
            page = requests.get(url)
            soup_jumbo =  BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
            titulo = soup_jumbo.find(attrs={"property":"twitter:title"}).get_attribute_list("content", "")
            precio = soup_jumbo.find(attrs={"property":"product:price:amount"}).get_attribute_list("content", "")
            print("Producto", titulo)
            print("Precio  ", precio)
            print('.')
            time.sleep(1)

            url = 'https://www.santaisabel.cl/salchichas-llanquihue-250-g-5-unida-2/p'
            page1 = requests.get(url)
            soup_santai =  BeautifulSoup(page1.content, 'html.parser')
            titulo1 = soup_santai.find(attrs={"property":"twitter:title"}).get_attribute_list("content", "")
            site1 = soup_santai.find(attrs={"property":"twitter:site"}).get_attribute_list("content", "")
            precio1 = soup_santai.find(attrs={"property":"product:price:amount"}).get_attribute_list("content", "")
            print("Producto", titulo1, site1)
            print("Precio  ", precio1)
            print('.')
            time.sleep(1)

            url = 'https://www.jumbo.cl/cafe-instantaneo-nescafe-tradicion-170-g/p'
            page2 = requests.get(url)
            soup_jumbo2 =  BeautifulSoup(page2.content, 'html.parser')
            titulo2 = soup_jumbo2.find(attrs={"property":"twitter:title"}).get_attribute_list("content", "")
            precio2 = soup_jumbo2.find(attrs={"property":"product:price:amount"}).get_attribute_list("content", "")
            print("Producto", titulo2)
            print("Precio  ", precio2)
            print('.')
            time.sleep(1)

            print('.')
            time.sleep(10)
    </py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

PyScript supports a wide range of modules and libraries that are not part of the standard library.

You can use third-party packages by specifying them in the `<py-env>` tag.

Try this, hope it will help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>python</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
    <py-env>
        - plotly-express
        - requests
        - beautifulsoup4
    </py-env>
    </head>
<body>

    <py-script>
            from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
            import requests
            import time

            print("Accediendo a la web..")
            print('.')
            time.sleep(2)

            url = 'https://www.jumbo.cl/salchichas-llanquihue-250-g-5-unida-2/p'
            page = requests.get(url)
            soup_jumbo =  BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
            titulo = soup_jumbo.find(attrs={"property":"twitter:title"}).get_attribute_list("content", "")
            precio = soup_jumbo.find(attrs={"property":"product:price:amount"}).get_attribute_list("content", "")
            print("Producto", titulo)
            print("Precio  ", precio)
            print('.')
            time.sleep(1)

            url = 'https://www.santaisabel.cl/salchichas-llanquihue-250-g-5-unida-2/p'
            page1 = requests.get(url)
            soup_santai =  BeautifulSoup(page1.content, 'html.parser')
            titulo1 = soup_santai.find(attrs={"property":"twitter:title"}).get_attribute_list("content", "")
            site1 = soup_santai.find(attrs={"property":"twitter:site"}).get_attribute_list("content", "")
            precio1 = soup_santai.find(attrs={"property":"product:price:amount"}).get_attribute_list("content", "")
            print("Producto", titulo1, site1)
            print("Precio  ", precio1)
            print('.')
            time.sleep(1)

            url = 'https://www.jumbo.cl/cafe-instantaneo-nescafe-tradicion-170-g/p'
            page2 = requests.get(url)
            soup_jumbo2 =  BeautifulSoup(page2.content, 'html.parser')
            titulo2 = soup_jumbo2.find(attrs={"property":"twitter:title"}).get_attribute_list("content", "")
            precio2 = soup_jumbo2.find(attrs={"property":"product:price:amount"}).get_attribute_list("content", "")
            print("Producto", titulo2)
            print("Precio  ", precio2)
            print('.')
            time.sleep(1)

            print('.')
            time.sleep(10)
    </py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muy amable. Al ejecutar el código me sigue dando error  
Accediendo a la web..
.
JsException(PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 692, in urlopen conn = self._get_conn(timeout=pool_timeout) File "/lib/python3.10/site-....